# Timestamps for spam and offensive flags not shown

Tags: bug, status-completed, spam, timestamps, flag-history

In the flagging summary page `/users/flag-summary/<id>`, the timestamp that the flag is raised for spam and offensive flags are not shown.

> [image: No timestamp on spam/offensive flag in flagging summary]

Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)? I can't think of any reason why the timestamp should be hidden.

From the [hims056](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182283/flag-time-is-missing-in-spam-type-flag#comment555105_182283)'s comment in [this duplicated question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182283/flag-time-is-missing-in-spam-type-flag): If you hover mouse icon on "helpful" or "decline/disputed" text it shows same timestamp in tooltip, while in case of "Spam" flag it doesn't show any tooltip.

---

#### 2015 update

To make sure this ancient bug hasn't been fixed by the recent redesign, I add current screenshots:

1. Hovering over regular flag shows the  UTC timestamp

   [image: flagged]
2. Hovering over "helpful" shows the time of handling as a relative timestamp, which is often... unhelpful.

   [image: handle]
3. And on spam/offensive flags neither thing appears:

   [image: offensive]

Comment: @Anna Status-Completed! But I can not see the timestamp yet.

Comment: @hims056: It was in one of the earlier build. It was completed, but somehow reverted to the current state.

Comment: Confirmed, it's the same way here.

Comment: Looks like the `title` attribute is missing from the span in the html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [Jarrod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon) this has been completed.  The spam/offensive flag will now show the date just like the rest of the flags in the history.