# Flag time is missing in Spam type flag

Tags: discussion, spam, timestamps, flag-history

Here is screen shot of my recent flag history,

> [image]

As we can see that after handling of flag by moderator each flag is showing the time when I flagged that post. But in case of flag like "Spam" or "It is not welcome in our community" it doesn't shows the flagged time. So my question, Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or another reason?

Edit :

From the [him056](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182283/flag-time-is-missing-in-spam-type-flag#comment555105_182283)'s comment If you hover mouse icon on "helpful" or "decline/disputed" text it shows same timestamp in tooltip, while in case of "Spam" flag it doesn't show any tooltip.

Comment: Off topic: Why do you use the custom flag for link only answers instead of the "not an answer" one?

Comment: @Yannis, because a moderator declined my flag with a message that "this should be link only answer". Let me show you the screen shot of it, just wait.

Comment: @Yannis [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Agxh7.png)

Comment: +1 Also in normal flags hovering on *helpful* shows us the time of helpful (i.e. when the flag marked as a helpful). But doesn't show for spam or offensive.

Comment: @hims056 you mean tooltip, Yes you are right I too marked it just now.

Comment: @Lucifer - Yes via tooltip. Please add this details too in the question. (since both are nearly related)

Comment: This is probably how it worked from the beginning hence by-design, but I do agree it should be changed. Offensive flags are probably stored elsewhere or treated in a different way.

Comment: @Lucifer found a dupe, would put a bounty myself but already got 3 active bounties. :/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes this is 100% duplicate, but that question is still pending for answer.

Comment: I know, so proper way of action is bumping it - bounty seems most fit I'll do that tomorrow if nobody else will. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd you mean Bounty on my question or old one ? and how much point's bounty ?

Comment: On the old one, hence bumping it. I would put 100 or 150 just because I have enough, you can put 50 though, it doesn't really matter. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ok, Status Completed :)

Comment: Wow, you feel generous today! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yeah I am too feeling same :P