# Active state for spam flags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, spam, offensive

Today, I saw my flags getting their state as **active** which are waiting for review.

But, the spam flags didn't get that.

[image]

Already, a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142823/timestamp-for-spam-and-offensive-question-not-shown) for spam and offensive flags for showing time was told status-completed by moderators, but it didn't get completed and a [pending](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179545/waiting-for-review-count-for-spam-offensive-flags) request too(that doesn't matter now).

Comment: As a comment, those two things that were flagged as spam clearly weren't spam at all. One was in fact a good question. Please only use these flags for things that warrant it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work?rq=1